# Possible to open window to external website, and close after X minutes?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I've been bouncing an idea around in my head but I'm not sure it's possible.  Thought I'd throw it out to the world and see what comes back.

I'm wondering if it's possible to, from website A that I control, spawn a browser window to website B that I don't control, and if the spawned window is not interacted with in a maximum number of minutes, close it to clean things up, but without having used any sort of frame?

My first instinct is that this isn't possible, since the window spawned with the site in it, would not be under my control and therefore couldn't be programmatically closed.  But maybe there's something I'm not considering.

Comment: not sure about not being able to close it, but you definitely can't monitor any interaction with it

Comment: Who would you like to be using this? Just you, on your website, or any user of your website?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm thinking any visitor of the website.

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah I'm sure I can't monitor interaction, but was wondering if there's any way to just have some sort of timeout on the window.  But my gut says that's only possible if it's in a frame of some kind.

Comment: actually, I was wrong, you can't close cross origin window, even if you opened it

Answer (score -2):

I would approach it by spawning a window with some of your script that checks for window interaction, but only displaying an iframe of the other site.

Comment: I specifically mentioned the desire to not use any sort of frame.

Comment: Ah, yes you did.  Unfortunately, with XSS I don't think this will be possible.

Comment: Yeah I kinda thought not but there are people out there much clever-er than I!  lol

Comment: lol right!  I'm sure you saw this already, but just in case ... there is a new message system with HTML 5 to pass messages between windows, but it too requires you to control the destination site.  The function is window.postMessage().  Good luck!